# add a small logo to the top right corner of a product images using shopify and liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am looking to add a small logo to the top right corner of a product image. The tricky bit is that I only want it to appear on product images that correspond to a given product tag. For example: Only Show overlay "FitLeftFitRight.jpg" over product images when products have the tag "Fit Left Fit Left".

I am using Shopify which uses Liquid as its markup language.

I would really appreciate this help.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, unfortunately SO is not a code writing service. Please post what you have tried, and any errors or exceptions you may have received.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the liquid file that contains the elements for the product image. My initial guess at solving this is to wrap the product image/slider in a `<div>` tag with the style `position: relative` and add the logo with styles `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;`

To only appear on product pages with the tag `Fit Left Fit Left` you can loop through the product tags and if tag is found show the logo, shown in the following code.

```
{% assign tagFound = false %}

{% for tag in product.tags %}

  {% if tag == "Fit Left Fit Left" %}
    {% assign tagFound = true %}
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

// Place this inside the product image wrapper <div> with position relative
{% if tagFound == true %}
  <img src="logo-url-here.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;" />
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you, Joey, I ended up figuring it out yesterday anyway but for future reference, it was what you later suggested i.e your above answer.